# Error in Spring Boot Rest API with JpaRepository

Tags: spring, spring-restcontroller

I am learning Spring with developing rest Rest API with JpaRepository.

I am getting below error and I am not able to resolve the issue. without below code it's working. added postgresql configuration in application.properties file. Please help me to resolve issue?

GameServiceRepository.java:

```
@Repository
public interface GameServiceRepository extends JpaRepository<Game, Long>   {

}
```

Error Message:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
```

2020-10-26 23:54:17.374 ERROR 3817 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Parameter 3 of constructor in com.pokkar.gameservice.GameServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.pokkar.gameservice.repositories.GameServiceRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.pokkar.gameservice.repositories.GameServiceRepository' in your configuration.

Comment: Please show the project package structure

Comment: Looks like an issue with package scan. Spring doesn't scan for annotations package where your repository class is

Comment: I added below annotation in root application 
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.pokkar"})

Comment: you can try @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.pokkar.repository"}) if using Spring Boot